# People's experience of Cloud Computing (using Force.com)

Tags: cloud-computing

I would like to know about people's experience of working with APEX and the SalesForce.com platform, was it easy to work with? How similar to Java and C# is it? What did you like? What don't you like? Would you recommend it? Do you think cloud computing has a long term successful future?

My reason for asking is that I am currently looking at a new position which involves working with APEX on the SalesForce.com platform. The position interests me but I just want to try and understand what I might be signing up for with regards the languages/platform as it is completely different from what I have worked with before.

I have seen lots of videos/blog posts online (mainly from the recent Dreamforce event) and they obviously are very positive but I was just after some experiences from developers, both positive and negative.

I find cloud computing a very interesting idea, but I am very new to the subject. The position I am looking at offers a fantastic opportunity but I was just after some opinions on APEX and the platform as I have no real world experience just what I have seen from the online videos.

I guess ultimately what I am asking is:

- Are APEX and the SalesForce.com platform good to get involved in? **Is development on the Force.com just a "career dead end"?**
- Is cloud computing just a fad? Or does it have a long term future?

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong place to ask such a question.

Thanks

Comment: Website hosts have existed for zillion years, but are were never stated as Cloud Computing. :P .... I guess other than hosting, there is nothing to cloud computing in real world.

Comment: @Pankaj zillion years?  More like 20.

Comment: @ Digger:Did you take the job or not?If yes are you satisfied?If not why not?I am asking because I am interested in a similar position

Comment: @user10326: No as I found that their were too many limits on what you could do. But, I would say think about what you want to do and make your own decision. I decided I wanted more freedom when developing solutions, you might not. Let us know what you decide, cheers.

Comment: @user10326 see some of the comments from the accepted answer below. I found them to be quite true (re: dead end) as I looked around. But that was just my opinion, yours might be different

Comment: @ Digger:Ok, thanks for the info. I understand what you are saying, I was wondering though if by dead-end you also mean that there are no employers interested in Salesforce.I mean usually e.g. SAP consultants can get good salary deals.Is it not the same with salesforce?Or you didn't go so far as to discuss salary or check if it is a "wanted" somewhat skill?

Comment: @user10326 I mean "wanted" and widely "wanted", could it build you a career you are happy with. I found it (or what I was asked to do in it) too different to what I wanted to do so I decided against it.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: Depending on your host, that's completely untrue. I'm thinking of Azure here, but it's a different environment altogether from a normal host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked about Salesforce and Apex specifically, I'll give you my opinion on it.

I have developed an application using Apex on the Force.com platform and found the tools and provided libraries lacking. Their implementation of the MVC paradigm is more like ASP.Net Code Behind than anything else.

They are slow to add new features for developer and instead are trying to turn Salesforce into some sort of social networking platform.

I think as a CRM, it is excellent, but as a platform for developing cloud based applications, it stops making sense for anything other than relatively basic data capture/reporting style apps.

As a developer, I can't help but think it's a career dead end.

That said, their REST API is nice enough and dealing with that will get you exposure to OAuth, JSON and all of that. I certainly enjoyed writing code related to that more than the core Force.com app.

Comment: Just a quick question, why a career dead end? Because they are slow to add new development features?

Comment: It could be a career dead end because you would be locking your development experience into a very specific platform that isn't transferable to other applications.

Comment: @KenLiu - I see your point but surely programming skills, techniques and practices are more important that the language or platform. A good programmer picks the right tool for the job because they know MANY tools.

Comment: You are correct, Digger and I certainly aspire to know as much as I can about **everything** but vendor lockin, incomplete libraries, and limited features and tools will put you at a disadvantage in the long term in my opinion. I should add btw, that I'm in favour of PaaS type services made available via Amazon or MS's cloud offering. I think the advantage of the the cloud applications, buzzword that it may be is being able to access your stuff from everywhere via any device you can think of

Comment: @ColonelPanic - fair point, I accepted your answer as it was the sort of thing I was looking for. i.e. experiences on force.com and using apex

Answer (score 3):

"Cloud Computing" is a bit of a marketing buzz word and not properly defined. Each specific implimentation has its own plus and minus points.

Comment: Cloud computing is not a marketing buzz. It an actual, quite cool concept, for computing and SaaS. The problem is that it has been slightly distorted, and mislabel by some as just hosted virtualized servers.

Comment: @AJC, Enlighten us please with a reference article that details the differences between hosted virtualized servers and the cloud.

Comment: @maple_shaft: Depends on the platform. In the case of Azure, it's being termed PaaS (Platform-aaS) mostly because of what it offers in the realm of queues, table storage, blob storage, the appfrabic, the CDN and a some of the "behind-the-scenes" platform specific things that support the SLA (ie. fault zones, upgrade zones, etc.). Very different.

Comment: @SnOrfus exactly my point. Its not clearly defined.

Comment: @TomSquires Certainly, I +1'd.

Comment: @maple - I don't really have any references to point you to, I'll look for them, but here is the fundamental difference between the two concepts, as I see them: The cloud is virtual environment hosting a myriad of SaaS products and other on demand services. Hosted Virtualized Servers is the infraestructure on which the Cloud stands.

Comment: @maple_shaft : cloud computing is almost the same as hosted virtualized computing *on demand* and *scalable*. If you can give me an example of hosted virtualized computing with these criteria that is not a cloud, or before the adoption of the word Cloud, then I would agree with you that cloud is a marketing buzz.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud computing is very expensive, very limited and over-hyped, IMHO, the only good thing about it is that you can accommodate an unexpected demand. So if someone DOS your web page, you can fire up more instances than the bot-net has, and the site will still be available.

Otherwise:

- automation is as hard as in local cluster
- you still need a sane system administrators
- lightning takes down clouds just like any other solution
- your information is stored at the 3rd party
- expenses are higher over 1 year period
- hardware is more limited
- capabilities are limited by the platform

I think best solution is local farm with fail-over/scaling to cloud on unexpected demand.

Comment: +1, That is an interesting concept about using the Cloud as the fail/over peak demand solution.  Do you have any references or articles on the subject that you can share?

Comment: I don't think you know what it takes to actually operate your own farm, otherwise you wouldn't say it is more expensive to operate on the cloud. The costs of servers, back-up servers, maintenance, and don't forget, a cooled server room with a fireproof door. Plus a lot more that I am forgetting. Cloud services are not cheap, but if balanced correctly, they are the cheapest option (If you don't mind the whole data-stored-offsite thing. Which to me is the biggest draw back). I do agree that the best solution is a combination of the two...

Comment: @AJC well that depends if your business really needs servers with a fireproof door, retina-scanned access, and to be under a mountain. If so, then yeah, local farms are expensive. If your server is Bob's old PC stuck on the back shelf, not so much.

Comment: @AJC, Google "server farm vs. collocation vs. cloud" You'll find plenty of comparisons, and cloud is always the costliest. Even if you order brand new hardware from Dell. It's not like you don't need maintenance in the cloud by the way. They all, clouds, fail and have worse reliability than collocation facilities so far, by an order.

Comment: @Coder - I gave a look at what you meant but wasn't convinced. Most comparissons did not took into account stuff like the cost of extra man power (claiming you would need = # of people for both solutions which is just not true) and conveniently ignore the fact that amazons' EC2 main strength is dynamic instance generation based on load balancing.

Comment: -1: I'm not sure what you mean about pt 1 but 2 and 6 depend on the provider, 3 depends on the provider's SLA, 4 is not a requirement (just usually cheaper) and 5 is anecdotal. The only point that I can see being true is 7 - but those are balanced by the benefits. I'm curious what platform you went with.

Comment: @AJC: Extra man-power? Why? Name me a reason why local servers need extra work, aside from swapping dead hardware once in say 3 years. Or maybe you don't do tape backups on say, AWS?

Comment: @SnOrfus: Which provider is that awesome one that I've missed? So far what I see is something like - http://chrischandler.name/the-real-cost-of-cloud-hosting, http://www.zdnet.co.uk/news/cloud/2011/08/08/lightning-strikes-amazons-european-cloud-40093641/, http://www.zdnet.co.uk/news/cloud/2011/08/10/aws-cloud-accidentally-deletes-customer-data-40093665/, etc. Nothing anecdotal. It's cheaper to buy dedicated hardware and let it idle without headaches, than it is to go through all the cloud costs. Cloud is only cost effective if you need to scale a lot for short amounts of time.

Comment: @Coder: That you're _seeing_ that is part of the problem. You're not speaking from experience. Personally, I've done a fair bit of work with Azure and with our product, it's a savings to our customer of a few $X00,000.

Comment: Actually, I am working with a cloud solution right now, and I'm shocked about the bills and limitations of the service. The customers where I suggested dedicated off the shelf hardware, have been happy for 5 years and the servers themselves were less than 1k bucks, one time purchase, including licenses. Google started with off the shelf hardware, and if I'm not mistaken, SO is also running on dedicated hardware.